# Object becomes different between inside and outside of jquery on 'mouseover function

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, mouseover

It's a wired problem for me.

Things like this:

```
//original draw 

//draw={
//  'color':'#fff'
//}

//some svg update, add new <li> html tag, and get new draw object

//draw={
//  'color':'#f00'
//}

console.log(draw); //color=#f00
console.log('--------------------------------');    
$('#list li').on('mouseover', 'li', function(e) {
    console.log(draw);//color=#fff
});
```

I use jquery to append new LI tag to UL, while the "draw" thing is a object to store svg path data. I use "live" to handle hover event with new tags, but it is deprecated, so I use on mouseover to replace it. Things look good in jquery event. But when I get svg data inside mouseover function, something happened, the "draw" object seems stil the old one, not the new one.

But When I print it outside, the "draw" object seems normal.

Anyone help me figure this out? Thanks very much!

Updated: Sorry for the wrong grammer and my bad English words.

Comment: `on` second parameter expects a string. Can you post a demo to reproduce the issue?

Comment: sorry, the demo is commercial. I have updated the descripttion.

Comment: Can you show how/where `draw` is defined?

Comment: By demo I mean  a [Short Self Contained Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). You don't have to post your proprietary code, just separate the piece of code that fails and try to reproduce the issue in isolation.

Comment: I see, but have no time to rewrite and wait the answer. I chang the solution, not use on mouseover. It seems work. Anyway, thanks for your answer, elclanrs~

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/on/

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )
```

The selector (second argument) of the `on` method should be a string.